# nested map function | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested, maps

I need to store category and subcategory in a map in Node.js, following code doesn't seem to work, can you please advise if I am doing something wrong here. ( PS - I am very new to Node.js & Javascript )

```
var list = [
    {name:'orange', category: "fruit", sub: 'citrus', price: 1.22 },
    {name:'pineapple', category: "fruit", sub: 'tropical', price: 2.22 },
    {name:'coke', category: "drink", sub: 'cola', price: 3.33 },
    {name:'beer', category: "drink", sub: 'alcohol', price: .44 },
]; 
function dictionary(list) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        var category = list[i].category;
        var sub = list[i].sub;
        if (!map[category]) 
            map[category] = {};
            if (!map[category][sub])
                map[categpry][sub]=[];
            map[category][sub].push(list[i].name);
        // map[category].push(list[i]);
    }
    return map; }
```

Comment: And what exactly doesn't seem to work? I tried it and only problem i see is a typo on this line `map[categpry][sub]=[];` **categpry** -> **category**.

Comment: this is what i get when i print it

Comment: fruit: [object Object]
drink: [object Object]

Comment: this is how I am printing it :

Comment: var map = dictionary(list);
for (var cat in map) {
    document.write(cat + ": " + map[cat] + "<br />");

Comment: var map = dictionary(list); for (var cat in map) { document.write(cat + ": " + JSON.stringify(map[cat]) + "<br />");

Answer (score 0):

This `dictionary` function will give you array of subcategories as a map.

```
var list = [
    {name:'orange', category: "fruit", sub: 'citrus', price: 1.22 },
    {name:'pineapple', category: "fruit", sub: 'tropical', price: 2.22 },
    {name:'coke', category: "drink", sub: 'cola', price: 3.33 },
    {name:'beer', category: "drink", sub: 'alcohol', price: .44 },
]; 

function dictionary(list) {
    var map = {};

    list.forEach(item => {
      if (!Array.isArray(map[item.category])) {
        map[item.category] = [item.sub];
      } else {
        map[item.category].push(item.sub);
      }
    });

    return map;
}
```

Sample output:

```
{
  drink: ["cola", "alcohol"],
  fruit: ["citrus", "tropical"]
}
```

Comment: actually solution suggested by Moh works well because I need to collect values by category and subcategory and eventually access back the same way for per category and subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you :)

```js
const list = [
  { name: "orange", category: "fruit", sub: "citrus", price: 1.22 },
  { name: "pineapple", category: "fruit", sub: "tropical", price: 2.22 },
  { name: "coke", category: "drink", sub: "cola", price: 3.33 },
  { name: "beer", category: "drink", sub: "alcohol", price: 0.44 }
];
function dictionary(list) {
  const map = {};
  for (let item of list) {
    !map[item.category] && (map[item.category] = []);
    map[item.category].push(item.sub);
  }
  console.log(map);
  return map;
}

dictionary(list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sachin, Moh's solution works for me.